# Gatsbyjs – Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: gatsby

I'm struggling with adding a react component to my Gatsbyjs project. It's a marquee ticker that's supposed to pick up date and title of latest posts in the blog and display them in the react component.

However I'm running into this:

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component 
repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate.
React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

As I've been able to gather, you're not supposed to put setState within render, but I don't see how to circumvent this in my use case.

Working demo code here: https://github.com/intelligence/marquee-issue

Here's the component where I try to use the react component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";
import Malarquee from 'react-malarquee';


export default () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        allMarkdownRemark(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC } limit: 10) {
          totalCount
          edges {
            node {
              id
              frontmatter {
                title
                date(formatString: "YYYY.MM.DD")
              }
              fields {
                slug
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <div>
        <div>
            {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => (
              <span key={node.id}>
                {node.frontmatter.date} {node.frontmatter.title}
              </span>
            ))}
        </div>
        <div>
          <Malarquee><span>We Are </span><span>Inline, so we </span><span>don't stack</span></Malarquee>
        </div>
      </div>
    )}
  />
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Malarquee library is to blame. It passes `this.setupContentMeasuring` as a `ref`, which will result in that method being called on each `render`. That method calls another (`measureContent`) that calls `setState`, resulting in `render` being called again if `setState` results in state changes.